# Import private key in HSM Luna SA

Tags: private-key, bip32-hd-wallets, wallet-security, private-key-import

I need some clarification on how keys are imported into a HSM Luna SA. I should import BIP 32 private keys of multisign wallets. There are currently two keys: one for the user and one held by the company that would like to start using HSMs.

> I start with a general question: is it better to keep all the
> individual private keys in the hsm or a single master key that is used
> to encrypt the private keys of the wallets?
>
> How are BIP32 keys imported into an HSM? Is the serialized format
> used?
> Are there any other keys that are needed for the import (wrap for
> example)?

I accept other advice on implementing the BIP32 with the Luna.

Comment: Have you asked [Thales customer support](https://cpl.thalesgroup.com/customer-support)?

Answer (score 0):

This is what is reported in the thales documentation:

```
Private Key Import/Export Private keys can be imported and exported with existing PKCS#11 functions. 
They can be imported and exported only if the HSM uses the key wrap model instead of cloning.
Import a key by calling C_Encrypt*() on the serialized key followed by C_UnwrapKey(). Exporting keys by calling C_WrapKey() followed by C_Decrypt*().
Use C_WrapKey() and C_UnwrapKey() to store keys off the HSM, or to move them between HSMs.
```

I don't know the use of PKCS11;

> which key is used for the wrap?